# Multipe rewrite urls : domain.tld/posts.php?blog=&id= to domain.tld/posts/blog/id

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How i can rewrite my urls
from this
**domain.tld/posts.php?blog=&id=**

to this one:

**domain.tld/posts/blog/id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your url in script to form: `/posts/blog/id` and rewrite this with `mod_rewrite`.

content of `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?$ $1.php?blog=$2&id=$3
</IfModule>
```

for example: for `http://so.localhost/posts/YourBlog/YourID` and `posts.php` with code:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  'blog' => string 'YourBlog' (length=8)
  'id' => string 'YourID' (length=6)
```

I hope I helped.